# biojava package import error

Tags: java, bioinformatics, biojava

I have downloaded biojava jar files and kept in my classpath. I am trying example to test from : http://www.biojava.org/wiki/BioJava:CookBook:Core:FastaReadWrite

but, it gives me error :

```
error: package org.biojava3.core.sequence does not exist   
import org.biojava3.core.sequence.ProteinSequence;
```

I have 24 errors of the example file shown in site. I have kept jar files in class path. then why this gave me error? Did i miss any step?

Comment: Which version of biojava have you downloaded? There are plenty of them...

Comment: i have downloaded 3.07 from http://biojava.org/wiki/BioJava:Download#Manual_Download

Answer (score 2):

Please check your classpath settings and biojava version.

I took the example from the webpage in combination with version 3.0.7 of biojava.
Here is what I have done

- Download the biojava.jar

  ```
  wget http://biojava.org/download/maven/org/biojava/biojava3-core/3.0.7/biojava3-core-3.0.7.jar
  ```
- Create a Java file `FastaOpen.java` containing the code taken from your link
- Compile

  ```
  javac -cp .:biojava3-core-3.0.7.jar FastaOpen.java
  ```
- Execute

  ```
  java -cp .:biojava3-core-3.0.7.jar FastaOpen
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
  at FastaOpen.main(FastaOpen.java:20)
  ```

The exception is OK, as I did not specify a filename. 
So, for me the example is working. And if I do not specify the classpath at compile time I get the same errors as you do, e.g.:

```
FastaOpen.java:5: error: package org.biojava3.core.sequence does not exist
import org.biojava3.core.sequence.ProteinSequence;
```

The description above works on Linux. On MS Windows you should try something similar to follwing commands (issued in Powershell)

- Compilation

  ```
  PS > & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javac.exe' -cp "C:\Users\stefan\Downloads\biojava3-core-3.0.7.jar" .\FastaOpen.java
  ```
- Execution

  ```
  PS > & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe' -cp "C:\Users\stefan\Downloads\biojava3-core-3.0.7.jar;C:\Users\stefan\Downloads" FastaOpen
  ```

  (Both files, java source/class and jar reside in the `Downloads` directory.

Comment: can you tell me what steps u did after downloading. i did the same but im still in the error tank.

Comment: Nothing special. I just ensured by the `-cp` that the biojava jar is in classpath. Do you compile on the command line?

Comment: What does your classpath look like?

Comment: i kept all jars in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin" and then i added that path in environment variables. is that so?

Comment: Hmm, not really. You should not put JAR files into the `bin` directory of the JRE. This directory should contain only binaries/ executables of the JRE. Usually, you put your JARs into a separate `lib` folder in your Java project directory. In my/ our case I skipped this step and have the java file and JAR file in the same directory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40416/discussion-between-stefan-freitag-and-sam)

Comment: u r a v helpful person without getting pissed. thanks